# How can I make front page to display custom taxonomy page?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates

If I have this URL for my custom taxonomy term `http://example.com/work_type/vehicle-transporting/` how can I show it as the main page `http://example.com/` like it is available to do for the static pages at `Setings` > `Reading` menu?

`.htaccess` solutions are acceptable, changing theme's `index.php` is not.

Update:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/work_type/vehicle-transporting/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [P]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Why it didn't help?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/work_type/vehicle-transporting/`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [P]`

I tried this but got no success

Comment: You're rewriting it in wrong direction, I guess. But why don't you use static front page and then use `front-page.php` template to show posts from this taxonomy? Or just use `home.php` template?

Comment: Just want to do it in one .php file, especially if it is possible.

Comment: It is possible, but it's not nice solution. A lot nicer one would be to use home/front-page template or to modify main wp_query (both solutions are described below in my answer - if you need any details, just ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @KrzysiekDróżdż While you should probably be able to do this it might be unnecessary work.

However, this works with I test it, just change the category/term name and the template name (the part in `get_template_part`), and maybe the `is_main_query() && $qry->is_home()` conditional if you need to:

```
function pregp_home_cat_wpse_104619($qry) {
  if (is_main_query() && $qry->is_home()) {
    $qry->set('category_name','aciform');
    $qry->set('ignore_sticky_posts',true);
    add_action('template_redirect','tr_home_cat_wpse_104619');
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','pregp_home_cat_wpse_104619');

function tr_home_cat_wpse_104619() {
  get_template_part('category','aciform');
  exit;
}
```

I have never tried to do this in production, so "when I test it" means that I've spent about 10 minutes and don't see any obvious problems. I make no promises.

Barely tested. Possibly buggy. *Caveat emptor*. No refunds.

Comment: Using `template_include` hook would be even nicer, I guess - you don't have to call `exit` then.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż : True, seems to work the same using that hook (which, for some reason, I forget about :) ).

Comment: @s_ha_dum yes, `get_template_part()` just what I need! My taxonomy-work_type.php and index.php became clear and looks in WP style. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1.**

One solution would be to use `home.php` template file, or use static page as front page and then use `front-page.php` template file.

You can use `get_template_part` function to include your taxonomy template inside, or use `template_include` hook to redirect one of `front-page`/`home` template to your custom taxonomy template.

**Solution 2.**

You can also use `pre_get_posts` filter to change main WP query in such way, that it shows only posts from this custom taxonomy.

Answer (score -1):

1. Copy your single taxonomy template code.
2. Paste that into your home page template. Or create a new one.
3. Add the following to the top of the page $post->ID = XX (XX being the ID of your post)
4. Set that template as your homepage in the WP settings.

Comment: Can you please add explanation how this solves the issue?

Comment: Sorry, I am not the one who downvoted.

Comment: @Nilambar - The question is how to display a single taxonomy as the homepage. My solution does that...